# How to store values in a bitmap array into an int array?

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

I have a bitmap array which contains 6 images. I want each image to be made circular and stored in an int array. I uses a for loop for getting each element and the method is applied in each iteration so that I get the circular images after the method gets executed.

Now I want to store these images in an integer array. How is that possible?

This is my bitmap array:

```
Bitmap[] images = { BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources
                   (),R.drawable.prof_pic_a),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources   
                   (),R.drawable.prof_pic_b),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.prof_pic_c,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.prof_pic_d,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.prof_pic_e,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.prof_pic_f)};
```

This is my integer array:

```
int[] rounded=new int[images.length];
```

This is my method call:

```
round=getCircularBitmapFrom(images[i]);
```

Comment: You can make a image circular but you need to store the image somewhere and get a reference to it. If you don't want to lose the original image you may require a copy of the same.

Comment: you can search on stackoverflow of how to save bitmaps in memory.

Comment: @GopalRao I thought of passing this final array into the image view in my Listview.Thats why am doing this.Is that wrong ?

Comment: @GopalRao I was correct.I got the desired output :) But one more problem is there.Can u help me with that please ?

Comment: @GopalRao okie :) Should i ask here or as another question ?

Comment: @GopalRao Okie.So,i am creating a chat application.Am using listview for that chat screen.i have two images of .png extension.i need these two images to be displayed alternately in chat screen.But,the chat bubble size should vary according to the text size na.I heard like 9 patch images are required for this.So i converted my images using draw9patch tool in android sdk.And i got 2 images of .9.png extension.So my question is how to use this in my listview ?

Comment: as same as using png images... set the 9 patch as background for `TextView`s..

Comment: @GopalRao okie.but there is one problem.i have two text views.one for displaying the name and other for chat message.Both should be displayed in chat bubble.So how to set background ?

Comment: can you show me some image how the bubble looks?

Comment: @gopal Please see this link http://oi62.tinypic.com/2gvq4pg.jpg

Comment: @GopalRao i am afraid whether the way i edited the image in draw9patch tool is correct :(

Comment: so how you want to display name and message in that bubble?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, converting and storing bitmap images in an array is not a good option since this may leads to memory leaks.

You cannot keep converted bitmaps to int array, you can use bitmap array for the same.

If your images are static one, then convert the images and store it in your drawable folder so that you can use integer array.

If your images are dynamic one, what I suggest is to use an overlay view on top of your imageview so that circular portion of your image is visible. This will reduce the conversion and storing overhead.